# PowerShell script runs fine locally, but fails as Azure Function

Tags: powershell, azure-functions

I have a PowerShell script that executes perfectly locally via VS Code, but when I deploy it to an Azure Function it fails.

The code in question is as follows:

```
$creation_date = $item.date.SubString(0,10)

$parsedDate = [DateTime]::ParseExact($creation_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd', $null)
```

When I run it locally, I receive the following output

**2023-12-04**

**04/12/2023 12:00:00 AM**

When I run it as an Azure Function, I get the following error

> *ERROR: Method invocation failed because [System.DateTime] does not contain a method named 'Substring'. Exception : Type :
> System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException ErrorRecord : Exception
> : Type
> :System.Management.Automation.ParentContainsErrorRecordException
> Message : Method invocation failed because [System.DateTime] does not
> contain a method named 'Substring'. HResult : -2146233087 CategoryInfo
> : InvalidOperation: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound InvocationInfo :
> ScriptLineNumber : 68 OffsetInLine : 1 HistoryId : -1 ScriptName :
> C:\home\site\wwwroot\TimerTrigger1\run.ps1 Line : $creation_date =
> $item.date.Substring(0,10) PositionMessage : At
> C:\home\site\wwwroot\TimerTrigger1\run.ps1:68 char:1 + $creation_date
> = $item.date.Substring(0,10) +*

From VS Code, I am executing the script in `PowerShell Core 7.3.10`

In Azure Functions, my runtime stack is shown as `PowerShell - 7.2`

I'm assuming that there is a runtime incompatibility, but I'm unsure where to head next. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is in `$item`? Try: `$item.date.ToString().SubString(0,10)`

Comment: $item is part of a foreach loop interrogating the results of '$req = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $download_root -Headers $headers -UseBasicParsing' / $jsonObject = $req.Data.
Basically it is a json element.

Comment: OK, so adding the ToString parameter in has removed the initial error. I now get "ERROR: Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String '12/5/2023 ' was not recognized as a valid DateTime." While my local execution of this returns a string of '2023-12-05', the Azure Function execution returns '12/5/2023 ', so I am assuming there are some regional settings that are affecting the returned date. Further investigation under way.

Comment: That is correct, the 3rd parameter in  `[DateTime]::ParseExact` sets the [format/culture provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iformatprovider) but as you apparently have different cultures and `$item.date` is probably already a `[date]` type (what is: `$item.date.GetType()`?), I would just let the PowerShell [Get-Date](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date) cmdlet figure it out: `get-date '12/5/2023'` <=> `get-date '2023-12-05'`

Answer (score 0):

My problem was definitely related to the Locale. I added some additional logging and found the format of the date value being returned, after which I added different code to achieve the result I was after.

```
$creation_date = $item.date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd").Substring(0,10)
$parsedDate = [DateTime]::ParseExact($creation_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd', $null)
$creation_time = $item.date.ToString().Substring(10,8)
$creation_time  = $creation_time.trim()
$creation_time_length = $creation_time.Length
If ($creation_time_length -eq 7)
{
    $creation_time = "0" + $creation_time
}
$creation_time_format = $creation_time -replace ':','.'
$Filename = $creation_date + '_' + $creation_time_format + '_' + "$recording_id.mp3"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use below code to get the required result:

```
using namespace System.Net

param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)
Write-Host "PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request."

$rithitem = @{
    date = '2023-12-03'
}

if ($rithitem.date -is [System.String]) {
   
    $creation_date = $rithitem.date.Substring(0, 10)
} elseif ($rithitem.date -is [System.DateTime]) {
    
    $creation_date = $rithitem.date.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
} else {
    
    Write-Error "Unsupported type for $($rithitem.date)"
}

$parsedDate = [DateTime]::ParseExact($creation_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd', $null)
Write-Output "Rithwik, Original date is: $($rithitem.date)"
Write-Output "Rithwik, Parsed date:   $parsedDate"
$body = "Hello, Rithwik Bojja. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    Body = $body
})
```

After Deployed to Azure.

**`Output:`**

[image]